# Do Until loop slow execution - alternatives to offset & select?

Tags: excel, vba

Code is looping through fairly large data (1000 rows by 20-ish columns) and deleting rows where there is not an error in the cell but currently takes 20 minutes to execute.
Looking for a way to speed up the process by removing the need for offset and select in the code.

I have tried turning auto-calculation off/on before and after the code but this did not noticeably affect run-time. Screen updating is already off.

```
Range("A6").Select
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    If IsError(ActiveCell) Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Else
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Loop
```

Leaves rows where the cell in Range A is N/A (IsError).
Runs as expected but takes a full 20 minutes to run.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not just autofilter and delete the visible rows in one hit, either manually or in code?

Comment: It's better to use cell(row,col) instead of Activecell. You can control it with index to iterate the rang u want.

Comment: Alternatively to what Rory commented, you could also populate an array with all rows with an error and delete all rows at once, after the loop has exited

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Quickest way would probably be to sort on Column A such that the blanks are pushed to the bottom in one large block. Then find the first blank row and delete everything below in one action.

Comment: quick win: disable calculation before the loop ! `Application.Calculation = xlManual`

Comment: Thanks all - I will look into each suggestion! I have already tried disabling the calculations, that came up in my research but it didn't have any noticeable effect.

Answer (score 3):

SpecialCells can quickly find all formulas returning booleans, numbers or text while excluding errors.

```
dim rng as range

with worksheets("sheet1")
    with .range(.cells(6, "A"), .cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup))
        on error resume next
        set rng = .specialcells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlLogical+xlNumbers+xlTextValues)
        on error goto -1
        if not rng is nothing then
            rng.entirerow.delete
        end if
    end with
end with
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - I haven't encountered specialcells yet, i'll look into this!

Comment: Thank you for the specialcells - I'm currently testing the following and seems to be working so far, no looping required:    Worksheets("Working Report").Range("A6:A" & lstrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, Value:=xlTextValues).EntireRow.Delete

Answer (score 0):

```
i=6
With ActiveSheet
     Do Until IsEmpty(.cells(i,1))
        If IsError(.cells(i,1)) Then
             i=i+1
         Else
            .Row(i).Delete
         End If
    Loop
End with
```

Comment: This will probably not work correctly. To avoid issues and compications when deleting rows, always start from the last row and go up.

Comment: @Patrick Honorez not sure why it will not work correctly. I didn't increase the index when deleting the row

Comment: Although it might work in this instance but it's considered bad practice. As per @PatrickHonorez suggestion, it's always safer to delete items from the bottom up. Also, your end condition is `Do Until F1 is not empty`.. again, it might work but what if `F1` is empty on a row but it's not the last row?. Better way to do it would be to get row count as per `user11026105` suggestion

Comment: Deleting from bottom-up is only problematic if you're using something like a `For-Next` loop as the index increases whether the row is deleted or not. In this case, `i` doesn't change if the row is deleted and therefore the 'usual' issue of skipping won't arise.